# How much time azure search take for index data

Tags: azure, search, azure-cognitive-search

How much time does azure search take to index data?
Suppose I am putting a single record at a time in azure search:

```
POST https://[service name].search.windows.net/datasources?api-version=2015-02-28-Preview
Content-Type: application/json
api-key: [admin key]

{
    "name" : "blob-datasource",
    "type" : "azureblob",
    "credentials" : { "connectionString" : "<my storage connection string>" },
    "container" : { "name" : "my-container", "query" : "<optional-virtual-directory-name>" }
}
```

So how much time it will take so I can read this data back from REST API?

Comment: This depends very much on your system and network.  The best (only?) way to find out is to try it yourself: execute the request under a *time* function.

Answer (score 0):

Your example shows creating a data source, not indexing documents. But, assuming you use indexing API (POST https://[service name].search.windows.net/indexes/index/docs), the delay before the just-indexed documents show up in search results ranges from instant to a few seconds, depending on the service topology and load.